# Suitable metrics to capture simple responseTime value over time using dropwizard and graphite

Tags: spring, timer, dropwizard, gauge, codahale-metrics

As I find in other examples,

```
Timer.Context timer = metricRegistry.timer("name").time();
....
timer.stop();
```

This gives `Timer` metric which [is](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/getting-started/#timers) "A timer measures both the rate that a particular piece of code is called and the distribution of its duration."

But how can I get the simple ResponseTime. Seems like `Gauge` is better fit, but then it doesn't help to plot the times continuously over time. So `Histogram` also doesn't seem to helpful.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gauge can be used to capture the response time and graphite provides the capability to plot the value over time.